# A href and url problems

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, laravel

I have this weird URL problem using html href attribute. By the way I'm using laravel.
I'll give you an example let's say I have this code in my website
`<a href="link1"></a>` and my current URL is `localhost/example/example`
And instead of adding link to my address like this `localhost/example/example/link1` it just adds it like this `localhost/example/link1` basically it removes goes one link back

I tried using `<a href"/link1"></a>` instead but it just removes all path like this `localhost/link1`

I tried searching what's the problem but I cannot find anything. I tough maybe it had to do something with .htaccess or laravel urls but I have no idea how to solve this(or maybe it has to do something with Apache). I just need that it would add links normally to URL.

Also i can't use laravel URL::request because i'm using JavaScript to generate dynamic content.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a base URL set in your HTML?  That would have this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://localhost/` is your domain.

If you are at `http://localhost/example/`, `<a href="link1">`, should point to `your domain` + `link1`

If your application is in /example/, I recommend you have a look a the base tag:

http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/base.html

So, supposing you have the following base tag because your application is in /example/:

`<base href="http://localhost/example/">`

That will make `http://localhost/example/`, the base for your links and forms.

`<a href="link1">` will open to `http://localhost/example/link1`

`<form method="post" action="link2">` will post to `http://localhost/example/link2`

Have a look at how links work in HTML:
http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using

URL::to('someseg/otherseg')

Comment: I said i cannot use URL::to because i'm generating continent with JavaScript I cant use php at all only JavaScript or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is controlled by the `base` element in the `head` of your HTML page.  You can retrieve this value with JavaScript (`document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].href`).  If you also retrieve the relevant portion of the page URL (`window.location.pathname`), you can do something with those two values to change the links to behave how you expect.

Simply changing the links to absolute by prepending `window.location.pathname + "/"` to them would work.